# Stop a sibling event in Knockout

Tags: sorting, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

There is a table in which sorting applied in Header on various columns.

In case when one column sorting is in progress/process and on same time other column's sorting is clicked by user.
It's not behaving with proper shorting.

```
<div class="table-col">
  Title
  <a href="#" class="image_rght" data-bind="click: function(data,event){app.viewModel.sort('Title')},css:{noclass: app.viewModel.sortBy()=='' && app.viewModel.sortDirection(),toggleup:app.viewModel.sortBy()=='Title'&& app.viewModel.sortDirection(),toggledown:app.viewModel.sortBy()=='Title'&& !app.viewModel.sortDirection()}"><img src="~/Content/images/up_down_arrow.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="table-col">
  Date
  <a href="#" class="image_rght" data-bind="click: function(data,event){app.viewModel.sort('StartDate')}, css:{toggleup:app.viewModel.sortBy()=='StartDate'&& app.viewModel.sortDirection(),toggledown:app.viewModel.sortBy()=='StartDate'&& !app.viewModel.sortDirection()}"><img src="/Content/images/up_down_arrow.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="table-col">
  Facility
  <a href="#" class="image_rght" data-bind="click: function(data,event){app.viewModel.sort('FacilityName')}, css:{toggleup:app.viewModel.sortBy()=='FacilityName'&& app.viewModel.sortDirection(),toggledown:app.viewModel.sortBy()=='FacilityName'&& !app.viewModel.sortDirection()}"><img src="/Content/images/up_down_arrow.png" /></a>
</div>
```

So I want to stop, other event of sorting when other one is in progress/process.

For Example: User clicked on **Title** for sorting as it's process is not completed and same time user clicked on **Date** column, then date column event should not be fire till Title sorting is not completed.

Comment: When you say sorting is in progress - is it an animation, or are your sorting functions running asynchronously and just taking that long?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of logic in your view, which usually complicates things quite a bit. Start out by adding the click handler to your viewmodel. Create an `isSorting` observable that you can use to check if you need to postpone an update.

In it's most basic form:

```
var self = this;

self.sort = ko.observable("Title");
self.isSorting = ko.observable(false);

self.onClick = function(sortBy) {
  if (self.isSorting()) {
    // Queue logic
  } else {
    self.sort(sortBy);
  }
};
```

I'd suggest using a helper method to create event listeners bound to the different categories. For example:

```
self.sortHandlerFor = function(sortBy) {
  return self.onClick.bind(self, sortBy);
};
```

Which you can use like so:

```
<a data-bind="click: sortHandlerFor('Title')"></a>
<a data-bind="click: sortHandlerFor('StartDate')"></a>
```

You can use the same idea on the active/passive state logic: create a factory method that returns a computed `true` or `false` via the viewmodel instead of the view.

The queue logic for your `sort` jobs is closely bound to your async code. If  you need help with it, I suggest you edit your question to add this part of the app.